# Azure Application Gateway + web apps = SSLLABS A+?

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-application-gateway

I hope you all doing good!

Question - is it possible to get A+ on SSLLABS with Azure Application Gateway and Web Apps?

[image: my_score_A]

My ciphers:
[image: ciphers]

Please assist.

Comment: It doesn't look to me that this is a programming question. I'd say this is possibly better on [webmasters.se]

Answer (score 1):

I believe one of the requirements for the A+ SSL Labs rating is Http Strict Transport Security (HSTS), which instructs the browser to make future requests to the server only in HTTPS and not HTTP.  This means you will only do an HTTP-to-HTTPS redirect once and future requests are not susceptible to Man-in-the-Middle (MITM) attacks.

The Application Gateway portal doesn't have a checkbox to enable this, but you can use a rewrite rule to add response headers, HSTS being one that is documented as being supported.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers-url#rewrite-types-supported